# Swift - After node is touched delay until it can be touched again

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In my game I use SKActions in a sequence to move a node (paddle in this case) to a certain location and back, this part is working fine. The paddle moves whenever the user touches it on the screen. My code for this is as follows:

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first!
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    let nodeTouched:SKPhysicsBody? = self.physicsWorld.body(at: touchLocation)
    let ballNode = self.childNode(withName: ballName)

    if nodeTouched?.node?.name == RpaddleName {

        if !paddleRTouched {
            paddleRTouched = true
            let Rpaddle = self.childNode(withName: RpaddleName) as! SKSpriteNode
            let startPosition = CGPoint(x: 301.7, y: 87)
            let newPosition = CGPoint(x: 226.7, y: 87)
            let moveToNew = SKAction.move(to: newPosition, duration: 0.5)
            let moveToOld = SKAction.move(to: startPosition, duration: 0.5)
            let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveToNew,delay,moveToOld])
            Rpaddle.run(sequence)
            paddleRTouched = false
```

However I need to create a 5 second delay during which the paddle cannot be moved if it toucher (e.g disabling for a period of time) . How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove he last line of the code above:

```
paddleRTouched = false
```

...and replace it with something akin to this:

```
    let allowPaddleTouchAction = SKAction.run {
        self.paddleRTouched = false
    }
    let allowTouchDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5)
    run(SKAction.sequence([allowTouchDelay, allowPaddleTouchAction]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give an alternative to the good [T. Benjamin Larsen answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741332/1894067) that could be useful in frequently situations similar to your, you can use the **SKTUtils** [library](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/swift3/SKTUtils/SKAction%2BExtensions.swift) with the `SKAction` extensions:

```
public extension SKAction {
    /**
     * Performs an action after the specified delay.
     */
    public class func afterDelay(_ delay: TimeInterval, performAction action: SKAction) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: delay), action])
    }

    /**
     * Performs a block after the specified delay.
     */
    public class func afterDelay(_ delay: TimeInterval, runBlock block: @escaping () -> Void) -> SKAction {
        return SKAction.afterDelay(delay, performAction: SKAction.run(block))
    }
}
```

So , when you need to perform an action after a certain delay you can do directly:

```
run(SKAction.afterDelay(5, runBlock: {
    self.paddleRTouched = false
}))
```